# Probability Distribution - Picking marbles

Tags: probability-distributions

There are 6 black marbles and 7 white marbles in the bag. Without replacing the marbles, we repeatedly pick a marbles until it is a white one. 
Call X: the number of marbles until we can pick a white marble.

What is the probability distribution of X? And find E(X), V(X)?

Answer (score 0):

At each iteration, we do not have a white marbles only if we have a black one so
$$
P(X=0)=7/13
$$
and then for $6\geq k\geq 1$, we have
$$
P(X=k)= 6/13 \times 5/12 \times ... \times (6-k+1)/(13-k+1)
$$
and 
$$
P(X\geq 7)=0
$$

Comment: I don't think "X=0" has any meaning in this case. If P(X=0)=7/13, P(X=1)=6/13,..., then P(X=0) + P(X=1) + P(X=2)+... >1 which doesn't make sense